# React Native - Best approach for processing heavy JS code without hampering performance / rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview

I was looking into some specific use case in react native where I would like to execute some heavy JS operations without disturbing the main thread that runs the UI and animations in react native.

Example would be to run a for loop 10K times as soon as the app component mounts or any animation sequence is triggered by user (ex. navigating to new view animation, opening some details page animation, etc).

If I execute following code just before animation starts,

```
// animate the item details page (from item list page)
onItemPressed() {
// Some JS code to mimic heavy processing
console.log('starting...');
for (let i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
  (Math.random() * 9999999) / 7;         
}
console.log('Finished');

// starting animation sequence
this.setState({animationPhase: 'phase-2'});
}
```

After running above code directly, the animation is laggy because of the code that runs before animation starts.

I was looking into following approaches:

1. Using  RN's [InteractionManager](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/interactionmanager#docsNav) - After reading the documentation, one can implement it as mentioned in docs - wrapping the for loop inside InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions() handler. This, however, does not solve the issue completely. There is another method under it called **setDeadline** which is poorly documented. I assume its useful for processing chunks of data instead of processing whole code at once. Not sure how to use it.
2. RequestAnimationFrame / SetTimeout  - Does not work as expected
3. React native threads/workers - Web workers like API to process tasks in background. This works properly with added advantage that we can send/listen messaged to/from the worker thread to start/stop the task execution. As per the documentation of [RNThreads](https://github.com/joltup/react-native-threads) , we can use it as -

   ```
   import { Thread } from 'react-native-threads'; // import it in the required component

   this.thread = new Thread('./JS_FILE_THAT_HAS_HEAVY_DUTY_CODE.js'); // create new instance of it

   this.thread.onmessage = (message) => {} // listen to messages coming from the JS file

   this.thread.postMessage('Start'); // post message to the thread


   componentWillUnmount() {
       // stop the JS process
       this.thread.terminate();
    }

   // In thread.js file,

   import { self } from 'react-native-threads'; // import current worker context obj

   self.onmessage = message => {    // Listen to messages coming from parent script

      // start execution

   }

   self.postMessage('Completed');  // post messages to parent script
   ```
4. Using WebView  - I have not tried it yet, but [this post](https://medium.com/@inkdrop/a-simple-way-to-run-js-in-background-thread-on-react-native-8fff345576da) seems useful in this case, but is it fine to inject stringified javascript into a web view? Not sure.

My questions are -

1. I would like to know more on RN Interaction Manager, especially the setDeadline() method - how to use it and what it does.
2. Which approach is better in such use cases?

Comment: JavaScript is "run to completion". If your processing code takes longer than 16ms you must use web workers or else you WILL drop frames.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a solid answer for you as I'm also not that familiar with `InteractionManager.setDeadline()`, but I think having a look at the tests can provide the insight you're after. Oftentimes, tests serve as a great substitute for the lack of documentation.

Therefore, have a look at the [InteractionManager-test.js, specifically L230-L261](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/512676c65eff0b1c2d526b591b596e0754cf9a79/Libraries/Interaction/__tests__/InteractionManager-test.js#L230-L261)

There, you'll find these tests...

```
it('should execute tasks in loop within deadline', () => {
    InteractionManager.setDeadline(100);
    BatchedBridge.getEventLoopRunningTime.mockReturnValue(10);
    const task1 = createSequenceTask(1);
    const task2 = createSequenceTask(2);
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(task1);
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(task2);

    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();

    expectToBeCalledOnce(task1);
    expectToBeCalledOnce(task2);
  });

  it('should execute tasks one at a time if deadline exceeded', () => {
    InteractionManager.setDeadline(100);
    BatchedBridge.getEventLoopRunningTime.mockReturnValue(200);
    const task1 = createSequenceTask(1);
    const task2 = createSequenceTask(2);
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(task1);
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(task2);

    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();

    expectToBeCalledOnce(task1);
    expect(task2).not.toBeCalled();

    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers(); // resolve1
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers(); // task2

    expectToBeCalledOnce(task2);
});
```

It appears to me that it's a way to divide up the work, which could be useful.

Your solution 3. is interesting. I'd personally love to see some code on this. I've no experience in this area, but that sounds exciting. I think a webview should definitely help to offload the work to a separate thread, but I've never used it for this case before.

Comment: Thank you for the tests,they provide meaningful insight about how the setDeadline should work,but I am still not able to picture it properly. I can think of it like getEventLoopRunningTime is the time from which the event loop(queue)is non empty and pushing the items to stack as it clears out. When I set deadline if 100 and runningTime is 10, as it has not exceeded the the deadline, all the tasks are run at once (one after another). In second case, as the time hits the deadline, task 1 and 2 is put in setTimeout (for how many period ? ) and executed as in order of timeout. Not sure if correct.

Comment: The threads code is interesting. good job with that. Why not just run with it if that works? As for your question, I'm not sure. My understanding is that it will divide it into multiple executions unless it can all be done within the deadline.